# Why class forward declaration is not allowed in function scope?

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors, forward-declaration, language-lawyer

Below code works fine:

```
template<typename T> class X {};
class A;  // line-1
void foo();  // line-2
int main ()
{
  X<A> vA;
}
class A {};
void foo() {}
```

Let line-1 and line-2 are moved inside `main()`. The function doesn't get affected but the `class A` forward declaration doesn't work and gives [compiler error](http://ideone.com/fksYD):

> error: template argument for `template<class T> class X` uses local
>   type `main()::A`

Comment: As far as I know, it's UB to use an incomplete type as a template argument to `std::vector`, by the way. Might want to conjure up a simple type yourself if you want a language-lawyer question, like `template <typename> struct Empty{};`, giving `Empty<A> vA;`. (Or is it truly specific to `std::vector`?)

Comment: @GManNickG, edited the question. It's for general usage with `template`.

Answer (score 4):

What you can observe is happening because, in C++, you can define classes inside functions.
So, if you place `class A;` in `main`, you are forward-declaring a class in scope of this function (i.e. `class main::A`), not in global scope (`class A`).

Thus, you are finally declaring an object of type X with a template argument of undefined class (`X<main::A>`).

Comment: "you are finally declaring an object of type X with a template argument of undefined class" -- Now that the template used is `X` rather than `vector`, I don't think it's a problem that `main::A` is an incomplete type. It's just plain illegal in C++03 to use a local type as a template parameter (14.3.1/2). AFAIK the restriction is removed in C++11.

Answer (score 2):

> error: template argument for template class X uses local type main()::A

This is the real problem - using a local type. In C++03 you cannot use local types as template arguments, because nobody had figured out how to *name* the resulting types.

What if you have several `class A` in several overloaded functions (again using the same name) - would the resulting `X<A>`'s then be the same type, or different types? How would you tell them apart?

In C++03 the standard passed on this, and just said "Don't do that!".

The problem was resolved in C++11 by deciding that `X<A>` using a local type `A` would be the same as if `A` had been declared in an anonymous namespace outside of the function, like

```
namespace
{
    class A
    { };
}

int main()
{
    X<A>   vA;
}
```

So, with  a newer compiler (or using a `-std=cpp11` option), you can use a local class, and we also know what it means.

---

However, forward declaring a type inside a function still doesn't mean the same as forward declaring it in another scope. They will just be different types.